# Calculating the sum and average

Tags: awk, gawk

My input file is price list of items, in that particular items, I want to calculate the sum and average of the rice items using `awk`?

```
Chenna Black |1|76.00|Chenna
Chenna White big|1|102.00|Chenna
Chenna White small|1|82.00|Chenna
Dhal-Gram|1|78.00|Dhal
Dhal-Moong|1|76.00|Dhal
Dhal-Orid|1|72.00|Dhal
Dhal-Toor|1|68.00|Dhal
Dhal-Green gram|1|88.00|Dhal
Rajma-Black|1|72.00|Rajma
Rajma-Pink|1|80.00|Rajma
Rice-Basmanthi|1|80.00|Rice
Rice-Boiled|1|42.00|Rice
Rice-Idly|1|33.00|Rice
Rice-IGBasamanthi|1|99.00|Rice
Rice-Karanatka Ponni|1|38.00|Rice
Rice-Nirapara Silky|1|235.00|Rice
Rice-Raw|1|40.00|Rice
Rice-Roasted Gram|1|100.00|Rice
```

Comment: yaa i tried like this BEGIN { FS = "|" }
  $4 ~  /Rice/ { n = n + 1; items = items + $3; }
  END{ if ( n > 0 ) {
     # print n,"items,","total items pay is:", items," items average:", items/n    # it prints in single line
  print n,"items," 
  print "total items pay is:" items 
  print "items average: " items/n
 
  }
   else { 
   print "item is not found "
 }  
 }

Comment: BEGIN { FS = "|" }
  $4 ~  /Rice/ { n = n + 1; items = items + $3; }
  END{ if ( n > 0 ) {
     # print n,"items,","total items pay is:", items," items average:", items/n    # it prints in single line
  print n,"items," 
  print "total items pay is:" items 
  print "items average: " items/n
 
  }
   else { 
   print "item is not found "
 }  
 }           8 items ,total items pay is :667,items average : 83.375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum and average of all rice items using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'|' '$4=="Rice"{s+=$3;c++}END{printf "sum: %.2f avg: %.2f\n",s,s/c}' file
sum: 667.00 avg: 83.38
```

Comment: same input file.but my question if you want to check through command line whether item is present or not.for suppose if you take rice item it will show message items is present.if you check any another item it will show message item is not found.